# How to frequent compare 2 dates for a huge set of objects (as cronjob) - nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, cron

My system has tasks that has a deadline (as date stored in the database) differ from task to another, I want to check frequently for these tasks if they exceed their deadline (basically with the current date I guess), and if so send a notification or execute a function

How can I make this function to be executed as cronjob or as it is without the help of cronjob.

I want to do this without making heavy load on the server

I'm using Express and [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) as ORM

I did see [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) as scheduler but i don't have the idea to implement something like this

I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use later package for this tasl like that:
https://github.com/bunkat/later

```js
var later = require('later');

later.date.UTC();

const DEDLINE_SCHEDULE = later.parse.text('every 1 min');

later.setInterval(createNotificationJob(), DEDLINE_SCHEDULE);

function createNotificationJob() { 
    // check are tasks exceed their dedline
}
```

and then every 1 minute you can check that if tasks  exceed their deadline and send notification.